# Restrict access to Laravel login page with certificate

Tags: laravel, apache, ssl, laravel-passport

I have an api project written using laravel which uses passport to generate api tokens. These tokens are used to distinguish who is hitting my routes so that the appropriate data is returned. All of this is working currently.

Both the token generation screens and api routes are contained within the same project. So hitting:

example.com

Brings you to the login screen. Once you log in, you generate a token and then use that token in subsequent requests to the api routes. The token is included when making requests for:

example.com/api/route1

example.com/api/route2/id1

Etc.

Toward the end of the project a requirement has come up to increase the security of the login page. I would like to generate a client certificate that I provide to my users that is necessary for accessing the login page.

How would I do this without affecting how I have the api routes setup? In other words, I am looking to have a workflow for users like this:

- import certificate into browser
- Now that certificate is installed, user can access login page
- login, generate token
- use token to make programmtic calls to api routes. These calls should not require the landing page certificate.

Is this possible? Or will adding the client certificate for logins affect the api routes as well?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your routes which require a certificate around a middleware. This middleware should to check if the certificate is installed otherwise redirect them to the pages accordingly.

Checkout the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-middleware

and

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gates and policies for certain actions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Lets say a user can update a post, but cant delete it. Those policies are helpfull for it